# Property updates not getting saved in java properties file

Tags: java

I'm trying to change some values in my config.properties file.There is change in values when I set them but it doesn't get saved. here is my code

```
public class Config {
String filename = "config.properties";

public void displayConfig() throws IOException {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    if (input == null) {
        System.out.println("unable to find " + filename);
        return;
    }
    prop.load(input);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(prop);
    Enumeration<?> e = prop.propertyNames();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) e.nextElement();
        String value = prop.getProperty(key);
        System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
    }
    return;
}

public void setConfig() throws Exception {
    File filename = new File("config.properties");
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
    prop.load(in);
    in.close();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
    prop.setProperty("db", "csv");
    prop.setProperty("user", "tej");
    prop.setProperty("password", "54321");
    prop.store(out, null);
    out.close();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(prop);
}

}
```

and the output when I call displayConfig,setConfig,displayConfig is like

```
{user=localhost, db=dtcc, password=12345}
db : dtcc
user : localhost
password : 12345

{user=tej, db=csv, password=54321, key=value}

{user=localhost, db=dtcc, password=12345}
db : dtcc
user : localhost
password : 12345
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's quite expected, since `displayConfig()` doesn't load its properties from the same location as `setConfig()`.

`displayConfig()` loads them from the resource config.properties at the root of the classpath, and setConfig loads and saves them in a file in the current directory.

BTW; even if the current directory happens to be in the classpath, I think `getResourceAsStream()` caches the stream content the first time it's called.

Choose your poison: either you want readable and writable files, and you should use file IO, or you want read-only resources loaded from the classpath, and you should use `getResource[AsStream]`. Don't mix both.